# How to solve collision detection in Java?

Tags: java, collision, detection

I know there's tons of tutorials out there about collision detection in Java. I have searched, read, and watched so many videos, tutorials, and articles about it. But I still am unable to solve it.

How I am currently detecting my collisions is through 4 rectangle boxes around each side of blocks or characters. This is similar in all game objects:

```
    public Rectangle getBoundsT(){
    return new Rectangle(x + 1,y,30,10);
}
public Rectangle getBoundsL(){
    return new Rectangle(x,y + 1,10,62);
}
public Rectangle getBoundsB(){
    return new Rectangle(x + 1,y + 54,30,10);
}
public Rectangle getBoundsR(){
    return new Rectangle(x + 22,y + 1,10,62);
}
```

And this detects the collision:

```
            if(getBoundsB().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsT())){
            y=tempObject.y - 64;
        }
        if(getBoundsL().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsR())){
            x=tempObject.x + 32;
        }
        if(getBoundsR().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsL())){
            x=tempObject.x -32;
        }
        if(getBoundsT().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsB())){
            y=tempObject.y + 32;
        }
```

My Player Object is 32x64 for size, and my blocks are 32x32.

Now this works, and it detects collision and stops the blocks, sort of. It will work when I fully cover the one side. Once I move over so that I have multiple collisions happening it will react to both, causing my player to teleport upwards, or towards the side. I'm not able to post an image of this because I need at least 10 reputation.

I don't know how to fix this problem, and I don't know if I have to completely redo everything with collision because I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: why do you add `1` to the top, left, and bottom bounds, and `22` to the right bound?

Comment: You are using rectangles covering outer parts of the player and the blocks with the intent of detecting whether a collision occurs in an up or down or left or right movement. This isn't going to work: you need to check the vector of the moving object to determine the position to which a player should be reset. And you'll need to assess all blocks before you calculate that point because a collision could be happening with two blocks at the same time.

Comment: Or are movements restricted to occur on a 32x32 grid?

Comment: Adding one to the top was an accident, this mustve been my older code on my flash drive. But adding the 22 is because the rectangle is then 10 in width and it extends to the barrier. I will look up what you're saying about vectors because that sounds promising.

About the accessing multiple at the same time. i have no idea, that never even occurred to me because i was just following an online tutorial.